# No database found to handle error with flyway postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I am new to Java, trying to setup a first API.

I have a Springboot app which connects to a postgresql database on a docker container.

I do manage to access the database from the app, so the database in on and accessible as per my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/portfolio
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

When attempting to setup migrations with `flyway` with the command:

> mvn flyway:migrate

I get the error:

> No database found to handle jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/portfolio

This is how the `pom.xml` for `flyway` looks like:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sqlMigrationSeparator>__</sqlMigrationSeparator>
                <locations>
                    <location>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration/portfolio</location>
                </locations>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/portfolio</url>
                <user>postgres</user>
                <password>123456</password>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
                    <version>10.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

**EDIT - adding docker-compose as requested**

```
version: "3.8"
volumes:
  db:
services:
  postgresdb:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRESDB_USER
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRESDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
        - POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRESDB_DATABASE
    ports:
        - $POSTGRESDB_LOCAL_PORT:$POSTGRESDB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
        - db:/var/lib/postgres
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    environment:
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@localhost.com
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
        PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050
    ports:
        - '5050:5050'
```

.env file

```
POSTGRESDB_USER=postgres
POSTGRESDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
POSTGRESDB_DATABASE=portfolio
POSTGRESDB_LOCAL_PORT=5433
POSTGRESDB_DOCKER_PORT=5432
```

Comment: Can you share your docker info? If you are using docker-compose, share the file

Comment: `localhost` seems rather unlikely. It is a Very Bad Idea™  to run both the database and the application in the same container. And @drum is correct: In order to know what exactly is going on, we'd need the `Dockerfile`(or the according part of the POM, in case you use the springboot plugin) and the `docker-compose.(yml|yaml)`.

Comment: docker-compose added as requested. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I am not running the application on docker at all. Only the database ( and pgAdmin).

Comment: That's quite odd. Can you run a `telnet localhost 5433` on the host machine?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Here is the result: ` portfolio nc -vz localhost 5433
Connection to localhost port 5433 [tcp/pyrrho] succeeded!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says `No database found to handle jdbc:postgresql`. This doesn't mean that the database is not accessible/running, but that Flyway can't handle the PostgreSQL database type. You should add this to the Maven Plugin dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>10.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note: latest Flyway version is 10.8.1

Based on: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3722

Comment: Thanks @Mar-Z. That was it. Only changed to my version which is 10.7.1