Flyway Configuration Issue: No database found to handle JDBC URL
I'm encountering an issue with Flyway in my Spring application. The error message is:
'flywayQuranDatabase' defined in class path resource [com/LearnTheQuran/configuration/LTQDatabaseConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flywayQuranDatabase' threw exception with message: No database found to handle jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quran

Here’s my configuration:
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.LearnTheQuran.repository", transactionManagerRef = "quranJpaTransactionManager", entityManagerFactoryRef = "quranEntityManagerFactoryRef")
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class LTQDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "quranDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
    public DataSource quranDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @DependsOn("flyway")
    @Bean("quranEntityManagerFactoryRef")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean quranEntityManagerFactoryRef() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(quranDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.LearnTheQuran.model");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProperties());
        em.afterPropertiesSet();

        return em;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties");
        try {
            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            return properties.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString(), e -> e.getValue()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }
    }

    @Bean(name = "flywayConfiguration")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.flyway")
    public ClassicConfiguration flywayConfiguration() {
        return new ClassicConfiguration();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flyway flywayQuranDatabase(ClassicConfiguration flywayConfiguration) {
        Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().configuration(flywayConfiguration).dataSource(this.quranDataSource()).load();
        return flyway;
    }

    @Bean(name="flyway")
    public FlywayMigrationInitializer flyway(
            @Qualifier("flywayQuranDatabase") Flyway flywayQuranDatabase) {
        FlywayMigrationInitializer initializer = new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flywayQuranDatabase, null);
        return initializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean("quranJpaTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager quranJpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(quranEntityManagerFactoryRef().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> securityBasedAuditorAware() {
        return new SpringSecurityAuditorAware();
    }
}

application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: Learn The Quran

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quran
    username: postgres
    password: pwd
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: classpath:db/migration/db/postgres
    schemas: public
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quran
    user: postgres
    password: pwd

I have verified that PostgreSQL is running and the database URL is correct. The org.flywaydb dependency is included in my pom.xml (2 child pom.xml have the dependency), and I can connect to the database using the same URL and credentials.

Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78096545/no-database-found-to-handle-error-with-flyway-postgresql/78097115#78097115
